# Emacs, forward & backward in React angle brackets

Tags: reactjs, emacs

Suppose you have

```
<Foo>
  <Bar>
    hello
  </Bar>
</Foo>
```

When I am at near `<Foo>` I want to go to `</Foo>` and vice versa.

Simple request, but it's been hard for me to achieve.

`forward-sexp` (not sure where it comes from) does the forwarding ok, but backward doesn't work nicely with `backward-sexp`

Comment: What is the major mode of the buffer?

Comment: @NickD rjsx-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C-c C-f` (bound to `sgml-skip-tag-forward`) and `C-c C-b` (bound to `sgml-skip-tag-backward`) seem to work fine in `mhtml-mode`. You are probably in `js3-mode` when you are editing React.js code, so you can either switch to `mhtml-mode` (which might not be desirable) or bind the commands above to convenient keys in the `js3-mode` keymap:

```
(define-key js3-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c C-f") 'sgml-skip-tag-forward)
(define-key js3-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c C-b") 'sgml-skip-tag-backward)
```

since `C-c C-c` is a prefix in the `js3-mode-map`.

EDIT: The OP has indicated that he is using `rjsx-mode`, not `js3-mode` which requires minor changes to the above. The main difference is that one needs to modify the `rjsx-mode-map` rather than the `js3-mode-map`. Another difference is that `rjsx-mode-map` does not define `C-c C-c` as a prefix key, so either the keybindings have to be changed to something else, or we make `C-C C-c` a prefix key in this map as well - here's one way to do the latter:

```
(let ((foo (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key rjsx-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") foo))

(define-key rjsx-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c C-f") 'sgml-skip-tag-forward)
(define-key rjsx-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c C-b") 'sgml-skip-tag-backward)
```

If you want to make this a permanent change, then create a function that does these three things and add it to the `rjsx-mode-hook` in your init file.